# docker -t name:tag . does not setup an image with name and tag

Tags: docker, build, tags

For example running the following command on the console in a folder containing a Dockerfile

```
docker build -t myname:1 .
```

does create the following:

```
$> docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>              <none>              bc383b03fa2d        38 minutes ago      65.8MB
```

I would have expected it to create:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
myname              1                   bc383b03fa2d        38 minutes ago      65.8MB
```

All examples I found seem to seamlessly work.
But mine ain't.
What am I missing here?

After having run the `build` (with the somewhat not complete result) then

```
$> docker tag bc383b03fa2d myname:1
```

leads to the desired outcome as I want it.

More infos as demanded by commenting people:

Docker Version 18.06.1-ce-mac73 (26764) (should be newest right now on 2018-09-03; I just did update it).
I am running it on a Macbook Pro.
I am trying to run the Postgres image; Dockerfile exactly copied from https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/36294f464a4253017c4d9e04657d5469556f27f8/10/Dockerfile
I placed the Dockerfile in the folder where I run the command in.
The issue has happened before with other images as well.

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour. Please post your dockerfile, docker version, and exact commands that you are writing in your console with the logs/output

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your build process. Please verify it.

Comment: try restarting machine or just docker

Comment: ...see changed issue description for commenters' requests...